# Auotocomplete showing only name which starts in caps

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I am working on a application with C#, SQL Server CE, VS 2010 and in it I am giving option of searching records.

If I search data with capital character I am getting record but when I tries with small caps I am not getting any record.

My requirement is as above SQL query

```
SELECT top ({0}) name FROM Expenses WHERE name like '%{1}%'
```

Screenshot when providing input in small caps.

[image: when providing input in small caps]

Screenshot when providing input in capital.

[image: when providing input in capital]

Code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database\Acadamy.sdf;Persist Security Info=False");

    con.Open();

    SqlCeCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    var fetchAmount = 10;
    var userInput = textBox1.Text.Trim();

    cmnd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT top ({0}) name FROM Expenses WHERE name like '%{1}%'",
    fetchAmount, userInput);

    SqlCeDataReader dReader;
    dReader = cmnd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dReader.Read())
    {
       while (dReader.Read())
          namesCollection.Add(dReader["name"].ToString());
    }
    //else
    //{
    // MessageBox.Show(@"Data not found");
    //}
    dReader.Close();

    textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;    
 }
```

What would be wrong with code?

Comment: Is your database file case sensitive perhaps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cmnd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT top ({0}) name FROM Expenses WHERE name like '%{1}%'", fetchAmount, userInput).ToUpper();
```

Comment: Can you use .ToUpper() at end. I have updated solution. please check this

Comment: It's working partially. Means it's shows result when name is in caps and we are giving input in small caps.